# rufus-scheduler thread dies after some time with JRuby/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, jruby, rufus-scheduler

We have a sinatra app running on JRuby 1.7.19 under Mizuno. Initialising rufus-scheduler as follows (using rufus-scheduler 3.0.9):

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1h', :first_in => '30s', :timeout => '30m' do
  Acme::ScheduledNeo4jBackup.new.run
end
```

The job is as follows:

```
module Acme
  class ScheduledNeo4jBackup

    def initialize(rack_env = ENV['RACK_ENV'])
      @rack_env = rack_env
    end

    def run
      if should_run?
        Acme.logger.info "Running neo4j backup from scheduled task"
        Acme::Neo4jBackupTask.run_backup
      else
        Acme.logger.info "Not running neo4j backup from scheduled task as node is not master or standalone"
      end
    end

    def cleanup
      if should_run?
        Acme::Neo4jBackupTask.run_cleanup
      end
    end

    private

    def should_run?
      return false if YamlProperties.backup[:strategy] == 'disable'
      return false if (['test', 'development']).include?(@rack_env)
      ClusterStatus.new.is_master_or_standalone?
    end
  end
end
```

So we have 2 hosts, and one of them should log "Running neo4j backup from scheduled task" and the other should log "Not running neo4j backup from scheduled task as node is not master or standalone".

This worked for 4 days and then the messages stopped appearing on one of the hosts.

I did thread dumps using VisualVM and found that the scheduler.rb thread was not running on the host that had stopped running the rufus job.

Bad host:

```
"Ruby-0-Thread-55: .../vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.9/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:283" - Thread t@150
```

Good host:

```
"Ruby-0-Thread-79: .../vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.9/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:283" - Thread t@175
"Ruby-0-Thread-10: .../vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.9/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:555" - Thread t@21
```

The application was not restarted and we did not see any stack trace, it seems that the scheduler.rb thread just silently died on one of the hosts.

The application is started with this command line:

```
"bundle exec mizuno -E $RACK_ENV -D -P $pidfile --start --jmx --threads 10"
```

How can we debug further?

Comment: Before throwing the stone at rufus-scheduler, have you tried without Mizuno? I tried to look for some Mizuno documentation but couldn't find much... What is this --threads thing, can it be incremented? Have you tried setting a clear error handler in rufus-scheduler (see its README for that)?

Comment: more context: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/pull/168

Comment: Hi @jmettraux, yes I opened that PR by mistake. I'm now running the app with my forked version with that code in, so we can log the exception. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I linked to the PR, I think it can inspire other people, removing the brakes on their investigative skills.